# Add-in of Git in Visual Studio 2005 using Git Extensions

Tags: visual-studio, git-extensions

I am new to Git and just installed Git Extensions (Windows Vista). The Git stuff does show up in Visual Studio (I can see Git toolbar commands), but doesn't appear to do anything.

The Plug In does appear to work in Windows Explorer - when right clicking a file in explorer I have a bar with Git Extensions. Choosing "Settings" does show an array of green bars in the Checklist tab.

I did a remove and new install of Git Extensions- not sure if this could have caused the problem.

Any pointers? What can I do to better diagnose the problem?

Any help much appreciated.

Gerard

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is a file open in Visual Studio. The buttons are only enabled when a file is open. I also read about a problem somewhere that the plugin didn't work because Visual Studio was installed on the D drive. Is either visual studio or your user folder located on a drive other then the C drive?